# Get actual error code returned by web service

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebrequest

I have a rest service given to me in django rest framework. I am trying to consume this service in C#.

Here is my sample code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://abcd.zyz.com/hello/pqr");

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";

System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

string data = "{" + "\"key" + "\":" + "\"" + value + "\"}";


byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(data);

request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

string strUserNameAndPasswordForHeader = strUserName + ":" + strPassword;

request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strUserNameAndPasswordForHeader)); /*Add username password to header*/

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    // Send the data.
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

var response = request.GetResponse();
```

The last line causes a web exception. When I try to get the status code I get 403 Forbidden. The user who wrote the service said it returns -5 when the password is incorrect. Returns -6 when user account does not exists. How can I handle these error values because for me, for each of these scenarios it always returns 403. Where can I see -5 and -6 in web exception?

Answer (score 2):

Non-successful HTTP responses (so a status code other than 2xx) will throw a [WebException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx) when calling [`HttpWebRequest.GetResponse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx). In order to still access the response, you can catch the exception and then access its [`Response`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx) property to still get access to the [`WebResponse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.aspx) object that was received from the server:

```
try
{
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    // handle successful case
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    if (ex.Response != null)
    {
        var responseStream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream();
        // do something with the response
    }
    else
        throw;
}
```